# How to change more than 1 state in React-easy-state?

Tags: reactjs, react-state-management, react-easy-state

I am not able to mutate more than 1 state through one function using [React-easy-state](https://github.com/RisingStack/react-easy-state)

I have used `batch` in my following example and also used mutation separately. However, the code somehow disregards my 2nd state.

piece of the code looks like this :

```
batch(() => {
  // batch is used to test out whether it will trigger both store changes.
  store.counter = store.counter + 1;
  store.sumNum = 10; // this is never updated/mutated.
});
```

for reproduction [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-easy-state-2rexu) to sandbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have any state called `sumNum`.

```
// your store

const myStore = store({
  rndNum: "",
  counter: 1,
  someNum: 2, <--- not sumNum
  showRes: false 
});
```

Change it to `someNum` and it works.